# Could be a bug, after I send and SMS the LAST_TIME_CONTACTED field is not updated

Tags: android

Contacts have a field called  LAST_TIME_CONTACTED, it is updated with the time after you make a call.

But as I noticed when I send an SMS by the inbuilt Messaging app, it does not update. Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be? Sure. It could also be that this is by design. The documentation for `LAST_TIME_CONTACTED` does not stipulate under what circumstances it is supposed to be updated.

Feel free to file an issue on the [Android issue tracker](http://b.android.com) -- if it is a bug, that is the best way to let them know about it.

Comment: Cool, please support it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8784#c0